# utl_raw.cast_to_varchar increase length of String

Tags: oracle, non-ascii-characters

```
select length(initcap(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(nlssort('Chloé','nls_sort=binary_ai')))) 
from dual
```

length - 6

```
select length('Chloé') 
from dual
```

length - 5

I am using this function to change the accented character to base character.

Comment: Thanks Praphul.  What is your question?  Are you wondering why the length differs between these functions?  If so, nlssort is responsible.  Some additional information would be helpful, such as your NLS globalization params (`NLS_LANGUAGE,NLS_CHARACTERSET`, etc.).  It would be helpful to `DUMP` these two items (instead of `length`).  At a glance, it could be that the second example has length of 5 with the literal character string ending in ASCII character 233, vs nlssort's extra null character (0) added to 5-length string ending in character 101.  But the extra data would be helpful.

Comment: Why do you want to change the accent character?

Comment: `length(initcap(...))` is fairly pointless.

Comment: When I try `dump(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(nlssort('Chloé','nls_sort=binary_ai')), 1016)` then I get `Typ=1 Len=6 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: 63,68,6c,6f,65,0`, i.e. NLSSORT appends character (0).

Comment: The requirement is to remove all accented characters to base character and as it is name I have added initcap . Once I introduce this utl_raw function , there is a special character being generated at the end of field  :- "^@" in UNIX   which breaks the down stream process while consuming file . I have tried convert and translate , both are not working on some accented characters , is there a way to remove that NULL character from end , I tried TRIM , doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue :

SELECT INITCAP(REPLACE(utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(nlssort('Chloé','nls_sort=binary_ai')),CHR(0),''))FROM dual